# Angularjs failed to load template after build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

After i my build my angular app its showing me this error [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: app/app.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found). Please guys help me out!!!!!

app.html

```
<div class="root">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

app.component.js

```
    (function(angular) {
    'use strict'
    var app = {
        templateUrl:"app/app.html"
    }
    angular.module('mainApp')
           .component('app',app);
})(window.angular);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="" ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <title>IES</title>
      <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower styles dependencies -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- css files will be automatically insert here -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!--<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <app></app>
</body>
<!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower script dependencies -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- js files will be automatically insert here -->
<!-- endinject -->

<!-- inject:partials -->
<!-- angular templates will be automatically converted in js and inserted here -->
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- endbuild -->
</html>
```

app.module.js

```
 (function(angular) {
      'use strict';

      angular.module('mainApp',[
        'components',
        'common',
               ])
      .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
          $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HeaderInterceptor');
          console.log("Configuration Hook");
        }])

      .run(['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
        if (typeof $rootScope.global === "undefined") {
            if (localStorage.getItem('user')) {
              $rootScope.global = {
                user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')),
              }
            }
         }
      }])

    })(window.angular, window.localStorage);
```

If you wanna see the whole code here it is
https://github.com/masresha/testfiles/tree/master/IES/src

Comment: can u copy paster all the errors u get in ur console?

Comment: Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: app/app.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$compile/tpload?p0=app%2Fapp.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
    at vendor.js:28001
    at u (vendor.js:48139)
    at l (vendor.js:44936)
    at vendor.js:44980
    at h.$digest (vendor.js:46118)
    at h.$apply (vendor.js:46416)
    at l (vendor.js:40432)
    at v (vendor.js:40670)
    at XMLHttpRequest.C.onload (vendor.js:40587)

Comment: GET http://localhost/work/app/app.html 404 (Not Found)

Comment: did u try @Zooly answer?

Comment: Thanks @Salman. Please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47305243/4781975

Comment: No its not working still showing the same error.@Zooly @Salman

Comment: Have you solved this? please show us how!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yeah i did solve it. The reason it didn't work was i didn't add the views(app.html) in the production folder.  A rookie mistake. I hope u figured it out ur problem @ZiOS

Answer (score 1):

*app.component.js*

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict'
var app = {
    templateUrl:"./app.html"
}
angular.module('mainApp')
       .component('app',app);
})(window.angular);
```

You don't need to indicate `app` folder, you're already in it.

Comment: Its not working, now its showing me this error Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: ./app.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)